# How to refuse to work with graduate students?

Tags: thesis, advisor, supervision

How do you refuse to work with graduate students when they come to you and explain they want to work with you without necessarily being offered a job (e.g. a project that pays).

My advisor was very selective, he had conditions - students would need to take a course, Ace it, be in a percentage, then take a personality test, volunteer etc etc. He had many projects and million dollar fundings so it was just easy for him to have the authority and the department would be okay with this.

I am only starting and I have realized that I have been kind of soft about this, especially with international students knocking on my door and saying they want to work with me I accepted to be their supervisor. They have their scholarships too so I suppose that shows they have gone through a selection process, and it could be good for me. However, I noticed that it is actually very slow and time consuming to get them to a point where they start working on their own, and if ever happens, work academically (not just applications).

So I decided to be more selective. Then this student comes in and wants to work with me for all the wrong reasons. they have worked in field X for more than 5 years but wants to do their thesis on a new topic just so they will learn it, they didn't bother to take any related courses either. This is a student who deserted their MS some years ago and came back to finish somehow, sees literature review credits as "some checkbox". They signed up for the credits without talking to me (I didn't approve it, but the course is opened without a lecturer on paper, but students are expected to work towards their thesis with their supervisors)

When I explained them they don't have the necessary background, and I really don't have the time to start with a student who doesn't have the necessary beackground. They have insisted which would make me reconsider but the way they insist, using an authoritative language which is outright forceful, and it rubs me off the wrong way really, if I am a couple days late on reply, they send me emails (copy paste) repeatedly to my non work related emails as well (I don't know how they got it btw). Nothing shows up about the student btw as they are super secretive using initials only even for the email, basically a bit intimidating.  Their motivation is again a combination of wrong reasons imho. I don't want to waste my time and also their time. It is obvious that it isn't the right fit, I don't want to take up more students because I feel responsable for the ones I have, besides there will potentially be personal problems as well, my students are respectful and they are motivated by their topic, but I am not sure how to handle a student who thinks an alpha language is going to change my mind. but how to send this message across?

Comment: What about _sorry, I'm not taking students right now_?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not simply send him a polite rejection?

Comment: A personality test? What the hell?

Comment: Provide them a link to this topic and say you posted that.

Comment: Also, signing off with only their initials? Sending emails to your personal email? What the *hell*? Is this real?

Comment: Are those students "strangers" or do they have e.g. some course with you? If the latter, you might wants to announce in your courses that you don't want students before they ask you.

Comment: Just say no. You don’t owe the student any explanations. [No is a complete sentence.](http://think-human.com/no-is-a-complete-sentence/)

Comment: You said in a comment to another question that you are tenure track. In that case, this seems to be something you should discuss with your department head. Does saying _no_ as others suggest put you at risk? Even if the demands are unreasonable. That shouldn't be the case, but local culture may not be very helpful to you.

Comment: I think this is not really a question, it is a complaint.  Just say "No, please stop asking."  If this does not work, maybe it is stalking behavior.  Contact campus security.

Comment: The title does not match the question at all.

Comment: There are a few academics, who enjoy their position of power over students too much. I think you are a rare case that has not internalized it enough.

Comment: @Roland Actually, quite some of the ones that are stand-offish may have had bad experience in the past. It's almost impossible that in an academic career one does not encounter a non-negligible number of entitled students or candidates. The difficult part is not to become stand-offish despite that. There is no reason to assume that jerkhood is uniquely assigned to profs. It may just be more visible when it appears there.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper That is exactly what I did, I politely declined, gave him reasons and directed him to another direction which I really think is better for him, but then he keeps insisting and his language is I think a bit problematic. He used the name of another prof. in a way that suggests I should do it just because he recommended the student to me, the language he uses is borderline harrassment or at least some -alpha- language, and his motivations are not the right ones (e.g. working on this topic) - he basically even said literature review is just a checkbox anyway (it is a full course)

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim Yes both the personality test, and sending me email with initials only, to my personal account as well, repeatedly.

Comment: To anyone who doubt my intentions, I understand. Admittedly I have a problem with asserting authority in situations. I can't say well you are not cut off to work in this topic to anyone really, that makes me feel like BS. That's why I wrote nicely that I don't have time particularly for a beginner, and he should have done some prior work before etc etc. I try but I really fail at being authoritative, but I am not the best friend prof type either. I want some distance and respect, but don't want to feel like I am exercising some power on them.

Comment: I suppose perhaps giving reasons and putting them nicely made my message a bit open for brute force attemps then.

Comment: Well to add to my prev point, I take the role of a leader in a peer group, or with higher authoritative figures rather easily, particularly working towards the same goal. But asserting power over ranking is something I am terrible at.

Comment: @dusa So what? Just ignore

Comment: @lighthousekeeper well I don't want to undermine anyone's confidence or eagerness to work on a topic, you never know how they will take it. At least it is not my intention to make them feel bad about themselves. But I see where you are coming from. Maybe I don't need to explain myself at all. On another note though it is hard to ignore emails sent repeatedly to your work and personal email

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you really do not want to work with them and not even check them out if they are suitable candidates, the response is simply: "I do not currently have available slots for grad students." Not funding, but "slots". It means time, nerves, energy, whatever else could come into their mind.

If they have no funding, you say you have no funding for them and you do not accept students without funding.

However, if it is simply a case of you not being sure whether you should take them on, then I recommend preparing a few tasks that are relevant to the work you like to do. These should be pieces of homework that are introductory, but relevant to your field and take about 2-4 weeks of time to cover the entry literature and carry out. If they manage to do it, then you may want to reconsider not taking them. You may have a catch on your hand. Alternatively, you can set conditions of your choice.

Yes, if they want to work with you, you can set the conditions, no apologies. There is a reason for the classic "reluctant sensei" trope. It is a real technique to deal with this.

However, a student that thinks they can bully you is an absolute no-no, no matter how good they are. They are going to be nothing but trouble. So, here the answer is simple. First time: "Unfortunately, I cannot take you on as a student. Thank you for your interest." Don't give reasons. Second time: "As mentioned in my last mail from ..., I cannot take you on." Third time: silence. If they continue bugging you, divert their mails to spam or block them. If you cannot or are not allowed to do that, simply archive their mails without opening. Don't open them or you will be tempted to answer them.

You do not need to be outright rude yourself, but if they are, they have deserved the silent treatment. Keep in mind: if you know you will not change your mind, no matter how insistive they are, that will shine through and most of them will desist. If they believe to smell insecurity, they will pounce on it.

Comment: I suppose giving reasons and putting them nicely made my message a bit open for brute force attemps, or like you said "they smelled insecurity". I thought a simple no might discourage the student, so I felt like I should have given a reason. Because you never know how they take it, they may feel insufficient. I didn't think I would get a reaction like this.I think I should define some ground rules and stop explaining myself. Thanks.

Comment: @dusa If you know your "clients", you can afford to be nice. However, in the face of the unknown, you need to assume that overly friendliness will be abused. You do not need to discourage them. Your declining to supervise them is a decision about *your* resources, not theirs. The student tries to establish authority over you which they have no business doing. Your position should be polite, but firm and consistent. No need to be authoritarian, but you do not need to let yourself be treaded on, either. If the student is nice, you can advise them also what to do instead.

Answer (score 3):

"I only take students with a lot of experience in my field, because I don't have the resources to train them adequately".  I don't think there's a reason or need to come up with some excuse that may not hold up to scrutiny, or look bad when students in different situations start comparing notes.  In this case, I don't see any real problem with the truth.

Comment: OP should not give reasons, unless they are combined with practical evidence (see my suggestion about homework). Otherwise, they are open to be verbally challenged.